# jScrollPane set height

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

Somehow, i don't get it how i can set the height of jScrollPane.

http://tinyw.in/BLrg klick on newsletter 546. Now you see the scrollbar, scroll it by hand. You see, it goes quite deep into nothing. How can i make it as big as the wrapper? (600px)

It is a UL with a div as wrapper for jScrollPane. I've set the height of this wrapper to 600px, i tried several stuff but somehow i don't get it working.

This div gets hidden later on, i know that i have to reinitialize then, but maybe it matters. :)

Shouldn't it take the height of the element it is attached to?

Thanks!

If the newsletter is deleted (seems ppl having fun doing it) just press create new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe within your `initJScrollPane` function in the logic.frontend.js you have height being set with javascript after css is set:

```
var width = $('#elementsContainer ul').width();
var height = $('#elementsContainer ul').height();

$('#jScrollPane_Wrapper').css({'height' : height, 'width' : width});
$('#jScrollPane_Wrapper').jScrollPane({
    height: 600
});
```

I think, this could be getting the height of the whole content(`<ul>`), which is causing the wrong height to be set that you want.

Maybe changing it to this will fix it:

```
var height = $('#elementsContainer').height();
```

As that is set to 600px which I believe is what you are wanting it set too.

Comment: Ah yeah of course... Stupid mistake. :) Really haven't seen this. Thanks!

Comment: Do you maybe know how i can add a space at the start and ending of the scrollbar? Useing .jpCap or gutters doesn't work.